# Removing a line from a multi-line field if it contains a word in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, string

I have a text field in MySQL table that is populated like this:

```
ID     TEXT
1      horse
       cat
       cow

2      zebra

3      pig
       goat
       dog
```

I need to remove the line from a textfield if it contains a word **cat**. How can I do that?

Comment: Ideally you normalize this out so that you're not storing more than one value in a column in the first place.

Comment: If you have tried anything, can you show us? Might make it easier to understand what you are actually trying to do. This question is pretty unclear in it's current state.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton hmm, I thought it's pretty straightforward. I'm working with a text field format where I store multiple lines. What query should I use if I need to delete a certain line from the field?

Comment: @Steven Do you mean a "text field" as in how it's stored in your database, or how you are displaying it on a webpage? It's not clear to me what you mean by "delete a certain line from the field", because I don't know the answer to the first question.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton that's how data is stored in the database.

Comment: @Steven So you are trying to not return that entire record from the database, or just that single word and still return all the others?

Comment: What is MySQL version? Does the rows order in multi-line field value makes sense and the final state of the first row must be `'horse\ncow'` strongly, or final `'cow\nhorse'` in the first row is safe? Does the values of separate lines in the field may be duplicated, for example, `'horse\ncat\ncat\ncat\ncow\ncat\npig'`?

Comment: @Akina mysqlnd 5.0.12, as for the order, I would like to preserve the initial order, so `horse\ncow`. No, each line in the field is unique.

Comment: 1) Double each `'\n'` 2) Add `'\n'` from both sides of the value 3) Replace `'\ncat\n'` with `'\n'` 4) Replace `'\n\n'` with `'\n'` 5) Remove leading/trailing `'\n'`.

Comment: @Akina wow, that's a quirky solution :) I feel like it would be easier to just remove the `cat` and then remove `\n\n` if there are any, but I was hoping for a simpler one.

Comment: *I feel like it would be easier to just remove the `cat` and then* The value to remove (`cat`) may be a substring of a line (some animal which name contains `cat` substring), not whole line value...

Comment: "I have a text field in MySQL table that is populated like this" Please tell us how so we can help you - otherwise it would be impossible and just be based on guessing. Please edit your question and include relevant code.

Comment: MySQL is for the storage and retrieval of relational data. If you're not doing that then there's really no point using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not as easy as it seems. There are several possible cases: `'cat'` may appear in the middle of the text, or at the beginning of the text, or at the end. It may also appear alone in the text.

Fortunately, you are running MySQL 8.0, so we can use `regexp_replace()`. I would suggest two passes, like so:

```
select id, regexp_replace(
    regexp_replace(text, '(\n|^)cat(\n|$)', '\n'),
    '^\n|\n$', 
    ''
) new_text
from mytable t
```

This should properly handle all cases. Assuming the following sample data:

[image]

The query returns:

[image]

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5a401da5224ef67022d0de5331a186b2)**.

Side note: you can turn this to an `update` statement if needed.

```
update mytable 
set text = 
    regexp_replace(
        regexp_replace(text, '(\n|^)cat(\n|$)', '\n'),
        '^\n|\n$', 
        ''
    )
```

Comment: Thank you! It almost works. For some reason it does not update the field when there is only one line with `cat` in it. Maybe I can use PHP to help me with this task?